# What should I select to include in the package content?

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder, ipa, aot

I'm having an errors, and I think it's due to the fact that I don't include all the files in the package content when I compile the ipa, what should I put inside?, the AOT folder?, the .ipa file should be selected too?.

Thanks.

Comment: You aren't telling us what errors you are getting, what you are currently trying, how you are compiling, etc. These are things that will help us, help you.

Comment: I'm getting the "Uncompiled actionscript" error, after reading this: http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/ it shouldn't been happening, but it does. My other swf files are beign loadad from the documents directory, and I got that error, so maybe, I'm missing something when I package the files, like for example, I saw an AOT folder that I didn't include in the package, is that necessary?.

Comment: If you are loading a SWF on iOS, it cannot have any code in it. SWFs can only be used for assets on iOS.

Comment: Not true, they can contain code, the Air 3.7 enables it, but not for remote swf's, only for local ones.

Comment: I was not aware 3.7 enabled it (probably because I am using 3.6). Sorry I was not of more help.